# Getting SIGSEGV When Trying to Play an mp3 in AVAudioPlayer Using Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, avaudioplayer, iphone-4, segmentation-fault

I am trying to play an mp3 file with the following code.

```
 AVAudioPlayer player = new AVAudioPlayer();
 NSUrl mediaFile = NSUrl.FromFilename(monkeySound);
 player = AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl(mediaFile);
 player.Delegate = new PlayerDelegate();
 if(player.PrepareToPlay()){
     player.Play();
 }

private class PlayerDelegate:AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

        public PlayerDelegate(){

        }

        public override void FinishedPlaying (AVAudioPlayer player, bool flag)
        {
            //Some Stuff Done Here               
        }
}
```

This is the error I get:
Stacktrace:

at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend (intptr,intptr) 
  at MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject/MonoTouch_Disposer.Drain (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject) [0x0002a] in /Users/plasma/Source/iphone/monotouch/Foundation/NSObject.cs:305
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) .runtime_invoke_void_*this*__object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) 
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x00038] in /Users/plasma/Source/iphone/monotouch/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:26
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in /Users/plasma/Source/iphone/monotouch/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:31
  at MonkeyShot.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in /Users/fencer04/Projects/MonkeyShot/MonkeyShot/Main.cs:14
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) .runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)

Native stacktrace:

```
    0   MonkeyShot                          0x000d0d25 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 343
    1   MonkeyShot                          0x0000f6f4 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 322
    2   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x992a345b _sigtramp + 43
    3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
    4   AVFoundation                        0x0047c28d -[AVAudioPlayer privCommonCleanup] + 50
    5   AVFoundation                        0x0047c339 -[AVAudioPlayer dealloc] + 51
    6   ???                                 0x0a2af91c 0x0 + 170588444
    7   ???                                 0x0a2cab1c 0x0 + 170699548
    8   ???                                 0x077520d6 0x0 + 125116630
    9   MonkeyShot                          0x0000f4af mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1332
    10  MonkeyShot                          0x001ed319 mono_runtime_invoke + 137
    11  MonkeyShot                          0x0029da57 monotouch_trampoline + 2527
    12  Foundation                          0x0140d94e __NSThreadPerformPerform + 251
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00e9f8ff __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00dfd88b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 571
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00dfcd86 __CFRunLoopRun + 470
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00dfc840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00dfc761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x0404b1c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x0404b289 GSEventRun + 115
    20  UIKit                               0x01cdfc93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    21  ???                                 0x09d530a3 0x0 + 164966563
    22  ???                                 0x09d52e74 0x0 + 164966004
    23  ???                                 0x09d52474 0x0 + 164963444
    24  ???                                 0x09d522cc 0x0 + 164963020
    25  ???                                 0x09d5241e 0x0 + 164963358
    26  MonkeyShot                          0x0000f4af mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1332
    27  MonkeyShot                          0x001ed319 mono_runtime_invoke + 137
    28  MonkeyShot                          0x001efa00 mono_runtime_exec_main + 669
    29  MonkeyShot                          0x001eedea mono_runtime_run_main + 843
    30  MonkeyShot                          0x000a3083 mono_jit_exec + 200
    31  MonkeyShot                          0x002a1697 main + 3838
    32  MonkeyShot                          0x00002809 _start + 208
    33  MonkeyShot                          0x00002738 start + 40
```

Debug info from gdb:

/tmp/mono-gdb-commands.0GDVJY:1: Error in sourced command file:
unable to debug self

===============================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries

## used by your application.

Comment: Hi Justin. Did you find a solution to your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your issue, but I had some issues using the C#-style delegate methods and AVAudioPlayer. If this is similar to my issue, using the "WeakDelegate" construct and exporting methods might be useful.